# htaccess Rewrite Rule for 301

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to get a URL setup with a 301 and I'm having zero luck getting this to work.  What I want to do is take a URL with id parameter and translate that into a nice clean URL.  An example is below:

Original URL

```
/11/video_player.php?id=123
```

Resulting URL

```
/lesson/123
```

Can someone help me write this permanent 301 entry?  I've tried this about 20 different ways from a dozen different sources and I must be missing something with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/11/video_player\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ lesson/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^lesson/([^/.]+)/?$ /11/video_player.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

`RewriteRule /video_player\.php\?id=(\d+)$/ /lesson/$1 [R]`

Not sure if its required but escaping the `.` and the `?` in the input route is not a bad idea, just to be safe.

When you're stuck on a nasty rewrite-rule it can be very helpful to enable debugging, which you can do by adding these flags:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

Obviously change the path to wherever you want. A higher-number in the `RewriteLogLevel` increases verbosity. Please note that this syntax is for 2.x. For 2.4.x the syntax has changed to something like:

```
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3
```

See the Logging documentation for details: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging